# Can I add different text color in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to add there text color in UITableView Cell.

I want to show like that in UITableView Cell.

Red, Green , YELLOW

However, following code can work only 1 color.

```
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
cell.textLabel.text=@"4:00 AM , 9:00 AM , 10:00PM ";
```

I want to show 4:00 AM with red color and 9:00 AM with green color, 10:00 PM with yellow color.

How should I write it ? Can I do like this in UITableView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to create custom cell by customizing the content view of the cell

[sample tutorial here](http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/77006/uitableview-adding-subviews-to-a-cells-content-view/)

Comment: I got it. I'm using UILable and [cell.contentView addSubview:country3Label]; method. Working fine =) Thank